# Ember.js: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have some straight forward code in my Ember.js controller that is throwing a JavaScript error. Here it is:

```
App.OptimalController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  site: 'Cats',

  isCats:     Ember.computed.eq('site', 'Cats'),
  isDogs:     Ember.computer.eq('site', 'Dogs'),
  actions: {
    chooseSite: function(type){
      this.set('site', type);
    }
  },

  siteObserver: function(){
    //todo make request
  }.observes('site').on('init')
});
```

In my template, I have the following snippet:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-justified">
          <li {{bind-attr class="controller.isCats:active"}}>
              <a href="#" {{action 'chooseSite' 'Cats'}}>Cats</a>
          </li>
          <li  {{bind-attr class="controller.isDogs:active"}}>
              <a href="#" {{action 'chooseSite' 'Dogs'}}>Dogs</a>
          </li>
 </ul>
```

As soon as I load the page my console spits out the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I'm simply trying to click the `<li>`, have it change the `site` property, and add the `active` class to the element.

is there something glaringly wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ember.computed.eq` doesn't exist, you probably meant to use `Ember.computed.equal`

http://emberjs.com/api/#sts=computed.alias